# Continuously running a program, memory leak

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks

I would like to run a script indefinitely. It look likes my current script, as represented below, causes a memory leak.  In addition I would like to retain the @time_value array since I need to cycle through the values for each new run.

```
  class Data

    def initialize
      first_method
      @time_value = [30, 60, 90]
    end

    def first_method

      # get some data; takes about 1 hour
      second_method
    end

    def second_method
      #process the data
      first_method
    end
  end

  d = Data.new
```

Comment: I think you'll need to provide us with some code that actually reproduces the leak. That said, that mutual recursion sounds like a bad idea and at the very least will eventually run you out of stack space. Why not just use a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perpetual recursion may not only continue to consume memory but will eventually fail with a stack overflow.  Change your indefinite processing to a simple loop.

```
class Data
  def initialize
    @time_value = [30, 60, 90]
  end

  def run_forever
    while true
      first_method
      second_method
    end
  end

  def first_method
    # get some data; takes about 1 hour
  end

  def second_method
    #process the data
  end
end

Data.new.run_forever
```

Comment: I don't really see how this is different from what I am doing, where my infinite loop is simply a matter of going back and forth between two methods.

Comment: Well ok, I ran a little script with a simple perpetual recursion and that stack overflowed right away.  The while loop goes on forever.  Thanks

Comment: @chief when you recurse but never return, you add stack frames with each method call. Eventually you run out of room on the stack for a new frame.  When looping, there is no stack growth.